# dictionary shared between objects for no reason?

Tags: python, class, data-structures, nltk

The following code is supposed to create a new (modified) version of a frequency distribution (nltk.FreqDist). Both variables should then be the same length.

It works fine when a single instance of WebText is created. But when multiple WebText instances are created, then the new variable seems to be shared by all the objects.

For example:

```
import nltk
from operator import itemgetter

class WebText:

    freq_dist_weighted = {}

    def __init__(self, text):
        tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text) #tokenize
        word_count = len(tokens)
        freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)


        for word,frequency in freq_dist.iteritems():
            self.freq_dist_weighted[word] = frequency/word_count*frequency
        print len(freq_dist), len(self.freq_dist_weighted)

text1 = WebText("this is a test")
text2 = WebText("this is another test")
text3 = WebText("a final sentence")
```

results in

```
4 4
4 5
3 7
```

Which is incorrect. Since I am just transposing and modifying values, there should be the same numbers in each column. 
If I reset the freq_dist_weighted just before the loop, it works fine:

```
import nltk
from operator import itemgetter

class WebText:

    freq_dist_weighted = {} 

    def __init__(self, text):
        tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(text) #tokenize
        word_count = len(tokens)
        freq_dist = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
        self.freq_dist_weighted = {}

        for word,frequency in freq_dist.iteritems():
            self.freq_dist_weighted[word] = frequency/word_count*frequency
        print len(freq_dist), len(self.freq_dist_weighted)

text1 = WebText("this is a test")
text2 = WebText("this is another test")
text3 = WebText("a final sentence")
```

results in (correct):

```
4 4
4 4
3 3
```

This doesn't make sense to me.

I don't see why I would have to reset it, since it's isolated within the objects. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your comment is blatantly wrong. Objects in a class scope are only initialized when the class is created; if you want a different object per instance then you need to move it into the initializer.

```
class WebText:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.freq_dist_weighted = {} #### RESET the dictionary HERE ####
         ...
```

Comment: If you do that, how can you share that variable with other methods in the class? Right now, I have other methods that call that using self.variableName

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much! You're fast and accurate!

Answer (score 6):

Your `freq_dist_weighted` dictionary is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. Therefore it is shared among all instances of the class. (`self.freq_dist_weighted` still refers to the class attribute; since there's no instance-specific attribute of that name, Python falls back to looking on the class.)

To make it an instance attribute, set it in your class's `__init__()` method.

```
def __init__(self, text):
    self.freq_dist_weighted = {}
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class WebText:
    freq_dist_weighted = {}
```

declares `freq_dist_weighted` so that it is shared between all objects of type `WebText`; essentially, this is like a `static` member in C++.

If you want each `WebText` object to have its own `freq_dist_weighted` member (i.e. you can change it for one instance without changing it for another instance), you want to define it in `__init__`:

```
class WebText:
    def __init__(self):
        self.freq_dist_weighted = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

> It works fine when a single instance of WebText is created. But when multiple WebText instances are created, then the new variable seems to be shared by all the objects.

Well, yes; of course it would work fine with a single instance when all one of them is sharing the value. ;)

The value is shared because Python follows a very simple rule: the things you define inside the `class` block belong to the class. I.e., they don't belong to instances. To attach something to an instance, you have to do it explicitly. This is normally done in `__init__`, but in normal cases (i.e. if you haven't used `__slots__`) can be done at any time. Assigning to an attribute of an object is just like assigning to an element of a list; there are no real protections because we're all mature adults here and are assumed to be responsible.

```
def __init__(self, text):
    self.freq_dist_weighted = {}
    # and proceed to modify it
```

Alternately:

```
def __init__(self, text):
    freq_dist_weighted = {}
    # prepare the dictionary contents first
    self.freq_dist_weighted = freq_dist_weighted
```