# List of python objects, each with their own dictionary of arrays. Appending to one appends to all

Tags: python, list, memory, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)
>   [dictionary shared between objects for no reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710689/dictionary-shared-between-objects-for-no-reason)

```
     class Player():
        zones = {}
        def __init__(self):
            self.zones['hand'] = []
        def InitHand(self):
            for a in range(5):
                self.zones['hand'].append(a)
lst = []
lst.append(Player())
lst.append(Player())
lst[0].InitHand()
print lst[1].zones['hand']
```

This prints "[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]", but I only initialized the 0th element...
Changing them to arrays as below fixes the problem, but for the life of me I can't figure out why this happens.

```
    class Player2():
        zones = []
        def __init__(self):
            self.zones = []
        def InitHand(self):
            for a in range(5):
                self.zones.append(a)
lst = []
lst.append(Player2())
lst.append(Player2())
lst[0].InitHand()
print lst[1].zones
```

This prints "[]" as expected

Comment: Related / dupe: ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't see any mutable default arguments in this question.

Comment: @MarkRansom: That's why I said 'related'. The principle is the same, the mutable attribute is shared between instances instead of function invocations in this case.

Comment: In the dict version, `self.zones['hand']` is a *lookup* of `self.zones`, which finds the class variable, and then sets the `hand` dict key. In the array version, `self.zones = []` is *setting* a new instance variable, which then *overrides* the class variable. In this context, lookups cascade to outer scopes, but attribute-setting creates new variables in the inner scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, all players share the same `zones` dictionary. Anything set in the class scope is a *class* attribute, not an *instance* attribute.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.zones = {}
        self.zones['hand'] = []
    def InitHand(self):
        for a in range(5):
            self.zones['hand'].append(a)
```

Comment: +1, but I would change that to, "anything set in the class scope is a class attribute," since instance attributes can be set in any context where instances may exist (including a class or static method).